# How CAN eye mask is defined?

Tags: can

On p.9 of App Note CAN Eye-Diagram Mask Testing (https://literature.cdn.keysight.com/litweb/pdf/5991-0484EN.pdf?id=2186889), the eye mask is defined 60% - 90% UI.  Does anyone know how 90% is defined?  My eye diagram touches the 90% UI mask and I don't know what can be done.  Does it mean I may get BER? If so, how bad?  Thanks.

Comment: It's 90% of the way from the first "bit boundary" to the next "bit boundary". How to find the bit boundaries has a bit of uncertainty, but it looks like they take the crossing point of the falling and rising edges to be the bit boundaries.

Comment: Can you measure the prop delay and jitter separately for different patterns?  Do you know if there is ISI induced jitter? This is from asymmetry and group delay error and impedance mismatch. By isolating the root cause you can improve it. The Rx clock is fixed by the Tx clock with round trip delay.  So the 90% (200ns) is early bit shift greater than prop delay (5ns/m). So what is your received bit shift +?\-?

Comment: It can also mean your Rx clock is 1% fast after 10 bits or 90% of Rx bit cell